# getting the value of the button clicked in a group of buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

html

```
<div id="group1">
  <button>buttonA</button>
  <button>buttonB</button>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$('#group1').on('click', function(event) {
  // get ONLY the value of the button cilcked
});
```

Is something like this possible without attaching an event to every button in the group?

Answer (score 4):

Add a target selector to the `on()`  and use `this` or `event.currentTarget` within the handler function to access the matching element the event occurs on

```js
$('#group1').on('click', 'button', function(event) {
  console.log($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="group1">
  <button>buttonA</button>
  <button>buttonB</button>
</div>
```